# How to know when to use Chrome Dev Tools: Performance vs Memory tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

Lets say I have a web app which is slow and I want to identify possible bottlenecks. I First would go into the network tab and see if the server is the problem, if network calls are okay then I should proceed with **performance** and **memory** tabs?

What is the use case of the performance tab and the use cases of the memory tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the use case of the performance tab and the use cases of the memory tab?

The **Performance** panel gives you a complete view of the performance of a page during a recording. This includes network requests, JS execution, parsing, rendering, painting, etc.

The **Memory** panel gives you detailed views into how a page is using memory. People mostly use it to debug memory issues. When a page gets progressively slower as you use it, that's sometimes a memory leak. When a page is consistently slow, that's sometimes a page that is using too much memory.

> Lets say I have a web app which is slow and I want to identify possible bottlenecks. I First would go into the network tab...

Actually, I recommend starting with the **Performance** panel. It can show you network activity, as well as a bunch of other page activity. Go to the Network panel after you've identified that the problem is a network problem.

1. See [Get Started With Runtime Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) to get familiar with the **Performance** panel.
2. [Record the page load](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#record-load).

Once you've got a recording, there's a bunch of different sections on the **Performance** panel that can help you spot various bottlenecks:

- The [**Network** section](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#network) can help you spot [network bottlenecks](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/issues).
- The [**Memory** section](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#memory) can help you see memory usage.
- The [**Main** section](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#main) shows you JS, parsing, rendering, and painting activity.

See [Performance Analysis Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#main) for lots more on the **Performance** panel.

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer kayce, oh man your also the techincal writer at google :D

Comment: a shame the links are dead